# Connecting to MS SQL server from android

Tags: android, sql-server

I am developing an android app where I need to connect to MS SQL database and save some data only. I have found a code that seems to be working, however i don't know how to verify that its working because i don't have a MS SQL database. Therefore, I was thinking if there are any free online hosted MS databases that I can try to connect to and execute some queries on from my app.

1. Does anyone know if there are such databases online?
2. Are there better alternatives that you can think of to do such testing?

Comment: How the sample code you have found connect to sqlserver database? I don't think that there is a sqlserver client driver for android, i think that it use some webservers. Can you give me a link of sample code?

Comment: First, you should never directly connect to an external MySql database (or online database of any kind) from your Android app, as you're running the risk of your credentials being exposed. What you -should- do, is send a request to your webserver, which will then in turn contact the database and then return the results to you in a form you can work with. This can be pretty easily done with a simply PHP script (ie. http://webcheatsheet.com/php/connect_mysql_database.php ) and I would recommend returning the data as a JSONObject

Comment: Here's a link to the tutorial which includes the source code. http://blog.althafkbacker.com/2013/10/android-and-microsoft-sql-ms-sql-server.html